# Linq Query with a Where clause in an Include statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to replace my big, ugly query; although ugly it works as desired:-

```
using (var ctx = new Data.Model.xxxTrackingEntities())
{
    var result = ctx.Offenders
        .Join(ctx.Fees, o => o.OffenderId, f => f.OffenderId,
        (o, f) => new { Offenders = o, Fees = f })
        .Join(ctx.ViolationOffenders, o => o.Fees.ViolationId, vo => vo.ViolationId,
        (o, vo) => new { Offenders = o, ViolationOffenders = vo })
        .Join(ctx.Violations, v => v.ViolationOffenders.ViolationId, vo => vo.ViolationId,
        (v, vo) => new { Violations = v, ViolationOffenders = vo })
        .Where(o => o.Violations.Offenders.Offenders.YouthNumber != "")
        .ToList();

    gvwData.DataSource = result;
}
```

with the following linq Query:-

```
 var result = ctx.Offenders
        .Include(o => o.Fees.Where(f => f.Amount != null))
        .Include(o => o.ViolationOffenders)
        .Include(o => o.ViolationOffenders.Select(of => of.Violation))
        .Where(o => o.YouthNumber != "" && o.FirstName != "")
        .ToList();
```

I am blowing up on the 2nd line of the query... once I add the Where clause... `o => o.Fees.Where(f=> f.Amount != null)`

The error message I get...

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

In addition, I tried writing my query as:-

```
   var result = ctx.Offenders
        .Include(o => o.Fees)
        .Include(o => o.ViolationOffenders)
        .Include(o => o.ViolationOffenders.Select(of => of.Violation))
        .Where(o => o.YouthNumber != "" && o.FirstName != "" && o.Fees.Where(f=> f.Amount != null))
        .ToList();
```

But then I get the following error:-

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

I know the concept is right, but I need help with the syntax.

Comment: what `o.Fees.Where(f=> f.Amount != null)` supposed to be. what do you expect from it?

Comment: I expect 1 item in my result variable per Fee item

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cant have a `Where` inside the `Where`, but you can use `Any` which will return a boolean

```
var result = ctx.Offenders
    .Include(o => o.Fees)
    .Include(o => o.ViolationOffenders)
    .Include(o => o.ViolationOffenders.Select(of => of.Violation))
    .Where(o => o.YouthNumber != "" && o.FirstName != "" 
        && o.Fees.Any(f=> f.Amount != null)) // here
    .ToList();
```

Comment: sweet. The query works! But now I realize that I get my Fees as a collection... for one item in result, there maybe multiple fee items. I want Fees and to be distinct.. 1 fee item per 1 item in my variable result..

Answer (score 23):

In **.Net 5** **Filtered include** feature is added (EF Core 5.0).

Supported operations are: Where, OrderBy, OrderByDescending, ThenBy, ThenByDescending, Skip, and Take

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var filteredBlogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts
            .Where(post => post.BlogId == 1)
            .OrderByDescending(post => post.Title)
            .Take(5))
        .ToList();
}
```

MSDN Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager