# Write where condition inside Include in linq query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

The below query is returning error:

> The property expression is not valid. The expression should represent
>   a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.

```
var list = this.DataContext
    .GetDbSet<Table1>()
    .Include(t => t.Table2.Where(i=>i.Active == true))
    .Include("Table2.Table3")
    .ToListAsync();
```

How can achieve the above query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq Query with a Where clause in an Include statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528223/linq-query-with-a-where-clause-in-an-include-statement)

Comment: @ZavenZareyan I have tried using "any" but it returns all the data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter cannot work in include. You need to download Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore from nuget. And use code below

```
var list = this.DataContext
.GetDbSet<Table1>()
.IncludeFilter(t => t.Table2.Where(i=>i.Active == true))
.ThenInclude(x => x.Table3)
.ToListAsync();
```

Alternative one

```
var list = this.DataContext
.GetDbSet<Table1>()
.Include(t => t.Table2)
.ThenInclude(x => x.Table3)
.ToListAsync();
list.Table2 = list.Table2.Where(x => x.Active == true);
```

Comment: Is there any alternative to achieve the above

Comment: @chinni I added alternative one without adding Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore. Edited post

Comment: need with in that query itself.

Comment: Impossible. Filter cannot work in include linq. Only way is to use Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore. That's all.

Comment: My pleasure. @Chinni